# (ASP. net calendar) search for specific days

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a question about a project where I am working on it. It is an asp.net system to retrieve employee's attendance from database by using calendar. when I used calendar to search for a specific day, it is working fine and display the employee's attendance in gridview, But now I want to search employee's attendance for specific days (Range of days "from -to") How can I do it?code for search for specific day:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dte = currentDate.Value;
        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dte, out date))
            FillGrid(date);
        else
            FillGrid(DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Comment: Use two calendars

Answer (score 0):

use a form which contain two calendars and a search button then , pass ur dates from - to in ur controller parameters. that